# How can I export data from a php site to Excel 97 (.xls) format?

Tags: php, excel

I have a user that must get data from one piece of software for import into another.  The data must be in Excel format and follow a template with multiple worksheets, so a .csv text export won't work.

I'd like to make this easy for the user by offering a page on the company site that allows them to download the data they need already in the right format, but I don't know how to get PHP to save anything in Excel.

I've been trying to hobble something together with tech that I'm familiar with.  I think I'm close, but I've run into a problem.

My idea was to have PHP execute a VB script (.vbs) that would create the Excel file.  I started out with a quick .vbs that created a text file and that worked.  When I tried to run a .vbs that creates an Excel file, it didn't work.

This is my PHP to execute each script.

```
exec('cscript.exe "'.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\makeText.vbs"');
exec('cscript.exe "'.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\makeExcel.vbs"');
```

Here is the makeText.vbs code.

```
set objFileSystem = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set objTextFile = objFileSystem.createtextfile("c:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\data\vbsTest.txt")

objTextFile.writeline("This is a test.")

objtextFile.close

set objTextFile = nothing
set objFisleSystem = nothing
```

Here is my makeExcel.vbs code.

```
strESSFolderName = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\data\"

set objExcelApplication = createobject("excel.application")
set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApplication.workbooks.add

objExcelWorkbook.sheets(1).cells(1, 1).value = "test"

objExcelWorkbook.saveas(strESSFolderName & "test.xlsx")

objExcelWorkbook.close()

objExcelApplication.quit()

set objExcelWorkbook = nothing
set objExcelApplication = nothing
```

When I load the page that run these scripts, the text file is created, but the excel file isn't.  I think it has something to do with IUSR permission to run Excel, but I don't know what to do about it.  I want to find a workable and secure solution.  I've read about a COM class that will allow PHP to interact with OLE capable software and a library called PHPSpreadsheet, but I don't really understand how to install or use these.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) should do what you need. If you don't understand how to use it, read the docs. Come back if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I was lost in phpspreadsheet's github page.  I didn't know you could download and install composer and phpspreadsheet from the command line.

For anyone else having this trouble.

https://getcomposer.org/download/

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/